# $5$ divides $2ax+b$ for some integer $a$,given $5$ does not divide $x$

Tags: recreational-mathematics

$x$ and $b$ are given.Let,$5$ does not divide $x$.
Then $5$ divides $2ax+b$ for some integer $a$.

How do i prove this? I have not gone through a course in number theory,so a general proof would be appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to assume that $x = 5\lambda + \alpha$ and $b = 5\gamma + \beta$, this ends up devolving into proving $5$ divides $2a\alpha + \beta$ where $\alpha, \beta  \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$ ($\alpha \neq 0$). This isn't the "clean" way to prove, but it is a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Framing your question around modular arithmetic makes things much easier. You want to show that if $x\not\equiv 0\pmod{5}$ then there is an $a$ such that $2ax\equiv -b\pmod{5}$. But $2x$ clearly has an inverse $\pmod{5}$ so setting $a\equiv (2x)^{-1}(-b)\pmod{5}$ we have our solution.

In case you're not too familiar with modular arithmetic, think of it like this. We can set $x=5q+r$ by the division algorithm, where $0<r<5$ ($r\ne 0$ because $5$ does not divide $x$). Then we can find a value for $a$ depending on $r$:

$$a=\begin{cases}-3b&r=1\\
-4b&r=2\\
-b&r=3\\
-2b&r=4\end{cases}$$

It is simple to check that each of these cases are satisfied by simply factoring out the $5$ in each $2ax+b$

Answer (score 1):

The slightly stronger statement holds true that $\,2ax+b\,$ is a multiple of $\,5\,$ for an $\,a \in \{0, \pm 1, \pm 2\}\,$.

If $\,b\,$ is a multiple of $\,5\,$ then $\,2 \cdot 0 \cdot x+b=b\,$ is a multiple of $\,5\,$, so $\,a=0\,$ works.

Otherwise, note first that if $\,u\,$ is not a multiple of $\,5\,$ then $\,u^4 = \mathcal{M}5+1\,$ where the notation $\,\mathcal{M}5\,$ denotes any integer multiple of $\,5\,$. This follows directly from [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), but is also easy to prove in this case, as to keep the answer self-contained and largely number-theory-free. Any number $\,u\,$ which is *not* a multiple of $\,5\,$ must be in one of two forms:

- if $\,u=\mathcal{M}5 \pm 1\,$, then $\,u^2= (\mathcal{M}5)^2 \pm 2 \cdot \mathcal{M}5+(\pm 1)^2 = \mathcal{M}5+1\,$, then $\,u^4=\left(u^2\right)^2$ $=\mathcal{M}5+1\,$ by the same argument;
- if $\,u=\mathcal{M}5 \pm 2\,$, then $\,u^2= (\mathcal{M}5)^2 \pm 4 \cdot \mathcal{M}5+(\pm 2)^2 = \mathcal{M}5+4 = \mathcal{M}5 - 1\,$, then $\,u^4=\left(u^2\right)^2$ $=\mathcal{M}5+1\,$ by the same argument as above.

Then what remains to be proved is that one of the numbers obtained for $\,a \in \{\pm 1, \pm 2\}\,$ is a multiple of $\,5\,$. Those numbers are $\,b-4x, b-2x, b+2x, b+4x\,$, and their product is:

$$
(b^2-4 x^2)(b^2-16 x^2) = b^4 + 64 x^4 - 20 b^2x^2 = b^4 -x^4 + 65 x^4 - 20 x^2b^2 = b^4 - x^4 +\mathcal{M}5
$$

But neither of $\,b, x\,$ is a multiple of $\,5\,$, so $\,b^4-x^4=(\mathcal{M}5+1)-(\mathcal{M}5+1)=\mathcal{M}5\,$, and therefore one of the factors $b-4x, b-2x, b+2x, b+4x$ must be a multiple of $\,5\,$.